# Render and display a view from another controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc

How can I call and render a view of controller from action of another controller. 
I have this, an action of Product Controller :

```
 public ActionResult SortedLists(List<string> items, string ShopID)
    {
        //Do sth...

        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "ControlPanel", new { ID = ShopID });
    }
```

And Index is the action(view) of ControlPanel Controller :

```
public ActionResult Index(int ID)
    {
         ViewBag.theRelatedShopID = ID;     
         return View();
    }
```

How can I render Index and display it in browser???

Comment: what's wrong with your code? what you are doing is to redirect to an action that return a view which should render the view itself

Comment: the problem is that after execute of Index action of ControlPanel the Index page does not display. actually nothing happens. I searched that and find out by this method the page won't be rendered!!

Answer (score 2):

```
public ActionResult SortedLists(List<string> items, string ShopID)
{
    //Do sth...
    db.SaveChanges();

    return View("~/ControlPanel/Index.cshtml", (object)ShopID);
}
```

Here we are passing the `ShopId` as model to the Index view. If this view is strongly typed to some model you should pass this model:

```
MyViewModel model = ...
return View("~/ControlPanel/Index.cshtml", model);
```

Comment: What do you mean by *nothing happened*? When you called this controller action hasn't it rendered the correct view? Could you be a little more precise in the problem descriptions and provide more details?

Comment: When I called this controller action hasn't it rendered the view. Just a # added to URL like this http://localhost:55161/#

Comment: I guess that you have some client side javascript which is messing up.